# Viewing MS Word .docx files in Midnight Commander

Tags: docx, mc

I want to be able to quickly view (with F3) the content of Word doc/docx files in Midnight Commander. MC's extensions file calls /usr/lib/mc/ext.d/doc.sh, which contains wv, antiword, catdoc, and word2x as helper programs.  On my system (debian), the first three are available, but none of them are able to deal with the newer docx format.

The obvious solution is to use LibreOffice:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" filename.docx
```

This works well, but how do I tell MC to use it and display the result of the conversion?  If I put this in ~/.config/mc/mc.ext, replacing the lines

```
View=%view{ascii} /usr/lib/mc/ext.d/doc.sh view msdoc
```

with

```
View=libreoffice --headless --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" "${MC_EXT_FILENAME}"
```

then I end up with a filename.txt file in the current directory, and nothing is displayed.  What I want to happen is for mc to do the conversion when I press F3 and discard it when I quit the viewer.  (I guess the converted file would be written to /tmp/ and removed on quit.)

Bonus: it would be nice if the displayed file would be word-wrapped, I suppose that could be done by using the wrap command?

Can I do this without having to modify /usr/lib/mc/ext.d/doc.sh, in my ~/.config/mc/mc.ext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [`docx2txt`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/docx2txt):

```
View=%view{ascii} docx2txt %f -
```

Also you don't need such a long conversion string in `libreoffice`.

```
libreoffice --cat %f
```

is enough.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not know about docx2txt.

Comment: See also https://packages.debian.org/buster/odt2txt, https://packages.debian.org/buster/catdoc. There're certainly more like that.